# Length of the common chord of $y^2 = x$ and $x^2 = y$ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the way to find this? Just hint and a little help is required.

Comment: Hint: (i) Where do the two parabolas meet? (ii) A picture will help you see what the question asks for.

Answer (score 4):

$y^2 = x$ and $x^2 = y$ share only two points in common.  One is $(x=0,y=0)$.  What is the other? Hint:  It will solve $(x^2)^2 = x$.

A common chord must be between two common points.  So what is the distance ($\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$)  between $(0,0)$ and the other solution for the other common point?